# C++ STL Set: Cannot find() last element inserted

Tags: c++, stl

I am in the process of writing an application in which I use the Set class in the C++ STL. I've discovered that the call to set->find() always seems to fail when I query for the last element I inserted. However, if I iterate over the set, I am able to see the element I was originally querying for.

To try to get a grasp on what is going wrong, I've created a sample application that exhibits the same behavior that I am seeing. My test code is posted below.

For the actual application itself, I need to store pointers to objects in the set. Is this what is causing the weird behavior. Or is there an operator I need to overload in the class I am storing the pointer of?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

#define MySet set<FileInfo *,bool(*)(const FileInfo *, const FileInfo*)>

class FileInfo
{
    public:
        FileInfo()
        {
            m_fileName = 0;
        }
        FileInfo( const FileInfo & file )
        {
            setFile( file.getFile() );
        }
        ~FileInfo()
        {
            if( m_fileName )
            {
                delete m_fileName;
                m_fileName = 0;
            }
        }
        void setFile( const char * file )
        {
            if( m_fileName )
            {
                delete m_fileName;
            }
            m_fileName = new char[ strlen( file ) + 1 ];
            strcpy( m_fileName, file );
        }
        const char * getFile() const
        {
            return m_fileName;
        }
    private:
        char * m_fileName;
};

bool fileinfo_comparator( const FileInfo * f1, const FileInfo* f2 )
{
    if( f1 && ! f2 ) return -1;
    if( !f1 && f2 ) return 1;
    if( !f1 && !f2 ) return 0;

    return strcmp( f1->getFile(), f2->getFile() );
}

void find( MySet *s, FileInfo * value )
{
    MySet::iterator iter = s->find( value );
    if( iter != s->end() )
    {
        printf( "Found File[%s] at Item[%p]\n", (*iter)->getFile(), *iter );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "No Item found for File[%s]\n", value->getFile() );
    }
}

int main()
{
    MySet *theSet = new MySet(fileinfo_comparator);

    FileInfo * profile = new FileInfo();
    FileInfo * shell = new FileInfo();
    FileInfo * mail = new FileInfo();

    profile->setFile( "/export/home/lm/profile" );
    shell->setFile( "/export/home/lm/shell" );
    mail->setFile( "/export/home/lm/mail" );

    theSet->insert( profile );
    theSet->insert( shell );
    theSet->insert( mail );

    find( theSet, profile );

    FileInfo * newProfile = new FileInfo( *profile );

    find( theSet, newProfile );

    FileInfo * newMail = new FileInfo( *mail );

    find( theSet, newMail );

    printf( "\nDisplaying Contents of Set:\n" );
    for( MySet::iterator iter = theSet->begin();
            iter != theSet->end(); ++iter )
    {
        printf( "Item [%p] - File [%s]\n", *iter, (*iter)->getFile() );
    }
}
```

The Output I get from this is:

```
Found File[/export/home/lm/profile] at Item[2d458]
Found File[/export/home/lm/profile] at Item[2d458]
No Item found for File[/export/home/lm/mail]

Displaying Contents of Set:
Item [2d478] - File [/export/home/lm/mail]
Item [2d468] - File [/export/home/lm/shell]
Item [2d458] - File [/export/home/lm/profile]
```

**Edit
It's kind of sad that I have to add this. But as I mentioned before, this is a sample application that was pulled from different parts of a larger application to exhibit the failure I was receiving.

It is meant as a unit test for calling set::find on a set populated with heap allocated pointers. If you have a problem with all the new()s, I'm open to suggestions on how to magically populate a set with heap allocated pointers without using them. Otherwise commenting on "too many new() calls" will just make you look silly.

Please focus on the actual problem that was occurring (which is now solved). Thanks.

***Edit

Perhaps I should have put these in my original question. But I was hoping there would be more focus on the problem with the find() (or as it turns out fileinfo_comparator function that acts more like strcmp than less), then a code review of a copy-paste PoC unit test.

Here are some points about the code in the full application itself.

- FileInfo holds a lot of data along with the filename. It holds SHA1 sums, file size, mod time, system state at last edit, among other things. I have cut out must of it's code for this post. It violates the Rule of 3 in this form (Thanks @Martin York. See comments for wiki link).
- The use of char* over std::string was originally chosen because of the use of 3rd_party APIs that accept char*. The app has since evolved from then. Changing this is not an option.
- The data inside FileInfo is polled from a named pipe on the system and is stored in a Singleton for access across many threads. (I would have scope issues if I didn't allocate on heap)
- I chose to store pointers in the Set because the FileInfo objects are large and constantly being added/removed from the Set. I decided pointers would be better than always copying large structures into the Set.
- The if statement in my destructor is needless and a left over artifact from debugging of an issue I was tracking down. It should be pulled out because it is unneeded.

Comment: Please take a look at the `typedef` keyword - there is no need for using macros to shorten type-names.

Comment: unrelated nitpick: no need to check pointers for null before deleting them. deleting a null pointer is safe.

Comment: Why are you using new everywhere this is not Java.

Comment: @Martin 
Wow, I wouldn't think I would need to explain what a _sample_ application is. The actual code is spread across many classes. Perhaps all the news may look funny, but this is not a real app. 

The problem manifested when items were allocated on the heap (where they need to be). A valid sample or test application would then need to allocate things .....ready for this? .... on the heap!

My issue is obviously not a matter of allocating heap versus stack. But thanks for the inane comment.

Comment: @AngryLuke: No your problems (from reading the code) stem from a lack of understanding of the language. As shown be the correct answer below. The fact that you are using new everywhere and not doing the appropriate memory management (or using the correct classes) (or understanding how delete works) (or understanding the rule of 3 (or 4)) (or understanding that you can have pointers to heap objects) (or understanding that C-String is pointless). If you learn to use the language correctly then problems like this don't occur. That is why I pointed out the incorrect Java style.

Comment: @AngryLuke: The definition of 'FileInfo` is completely wrong. It can be fixed by correctly implementing the rule of 3 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29 or simply using std::string to hold the name in.

Comment: @Martin York - Yes, it does seem that I cut out too much when I ripped out the internals for this post. You are correct, FileInfo is incomplete in this incarnation.

Comment: @Martin York - To your little less troll-ish comment, these are the assumptions I was saying you cannot make based on a sample application because the reason for doing things this way is lost when it's pulled from the actual application itself.

If you want to comment on the code, I wouldn't mind your feedback. But to make valid comments like this you need to know more about the actual application itself rather than a throw away code snippet. I'm going to add some "reason why I did it this way" to my original question and I'd love it if you could then comment on the code itself.

Comment: @AngryLuke: No. I stand by my original comments; even if the code is POC (sorry if you feel they are trollish). Rather than edit this question: Take each of the things I said above and ask a new question you are breaking 5 fundamental principals of C++. (OK fundamental is too strong).

Comment: The problem is in order to take your advice I must apply it in the context of the application. So your advice may or may not make sense. To try to get something helpful I'd like to address the points you made. 
-I assume you were referring to the main() when you pointed out the news. Those news are only there to reproduce the problem I was having of heap variables in a set.
- Did I miss something here? Unless you are talking about the lack of deletes on the end of main I don't see any improper memory management. I skipped deletes at the end of main because in this case they don't matter

Comment: (I wish I could format comments) You refer to not using correct classes, is this just char* versus std::string?
Understanding how delete works - is this because I have an extra if statement in my destructor? If not, could you clarify?
" (or understanding that you can have pointers to heap objects) " - I don't understand. Isn't this what I'm doing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your comparison function is wrong - it returns `bool`, not integer as `strcmp(3)`. The return statement should be something like:

```
return strcmp( f1->getFile(), f2->getFile() ) < 0;
```

Take a look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set).

Also, out of curiosity, why not just use `std::set<std::string>` instead? STL actually has decent defaults and frees you from a lot of manual memory management.

Comment: +1: the fester of `new` is a sign of bad coding in a C++ application.

Comment: Doh, that's a forehead slapper! Thanks!


@Metthieu Please see what a proof of concept application is. When reading code that was pulled out of a larger application to reproduce a problem, it may not make total sense to you. A good coder knows PoC code may look funny but can ignore that to find the true problem.

Comment: That's not enough to make fileinfo_comparator() correct. The comparison needs to enforce a strict weak ordering. http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html This does not happen when either value is NULL. It just so happens it does not fail above because you do not have NULL values in the test set above.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like your `FileInfo` doesn't work correctly (at least for use in a `std::set`). To be stored in a `std::set`, the comparison function should return a `bool` indicating that the two parameters are in order (`true`) or out of order (`false`).

Given what your `FileInfo` does (badly designed imitation of `std::string`), you'd probably be better off without it completely. As far as I can see, you can use `std::string` in its place without any loss of functionality. You're also using a lot of dynamic allocation for no good reason (and leaking a lot of what you allocate).

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

int main() { 
    char *inputs[] = { "/export/home/lm/profile", "/export/home/lm/shell", "/export/home/lm/mail" };
    char *outputs[] = {"Found: ", "Could **not** find: "};

    std::set<std::string> MySet(inputs, inputs+3);

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        std::cout 
            << outputs[MySet.find(inputs[i]) == MySet.end()] 
            << inputs[i] << "\n";

    std::copy(MySet.begin(), MySet.end(), 
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: even when (or really, *especially when*) `FileInfo` is more complex, it shouldn't attempt to re-implement string functionality on its own. It should still use an `std::string` for the file name, and implement an `operator<` that works with that:

```
class FileInfo { 
    std::string filename;
public:
    // ...
    bool operator<(FileInfo const &other) const { 
       return filename < other.filename;
    }
    FileInfo(char const *name) : filename(name) {}
};

std::ostream &operator(std::ostream &os, FileInfo const &fi) { 
    return os << fi.filename;
}

int main() { 
    // std::set<std::string> MySet(inputs, inputs+3);
    std:set<FileInfo> MySet(inputs, inputs+3);

    // ...

    std::copy(MySet.begin(), MySet.end(), 
        std::ostream_iterator<FileInfo>(std::cout, "\n"));
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. FileInfo in it's true form is actually a lot larger and holds data regarding a files SHA1 sum, size, mod time, state of the system when modified and so on. 

I trimmed it down because all that extra stuff was unrelated to my issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor:

```
FileInfo( const FileInfo & file ) 
        { 
            setFile( file.getFile() ); 
        }
```

`m_fileName` seems to be not initialized.